# How to check the existence DRY & Laravel-style of an object that many controller methods are working with?

Tags: php, dry, laravel

In a Laravel controller I have a couple of methods that all begin by fetching a database record, then after checking if data has been found either continue by rendering a view, or, in case of no data, go to a 404 page.

Here's an example:

```
<?php

function get_show_user($id)
{
    $user = static::get_user($user_id);
    if (!$user) {
        return Response::error('404', static::$some_common_error404_message);
    }
    return View::make('users.show_readonly_user_data')->with('user', $user);
}

function get_edit_user($id)
{
    $user = static::get_user($user_id);
    if (!$user) {
        return Response::error('404', static::$some_common_error404_message);
    }

    return View::make('users.display_edit_user_form')->with('user', $user);
}
```

I'm repeating the entire `if (!$user)` statement in these methods, even if they all do the same thing.

I'd rather like to do something like this:

```
function get_show_user($id)
{
    $user = Users::find($id);
    static::go404_if_null($user);
    return View::make('users.show_readonly_user_data')->with('user', $user);
}

function get_edit_user($id)
{
    $user = Users::find($id);
    static::go404_if_null($user);
    return View::make('users.display_edit_user_form')->with('user', $user);
}
```

What would be the best way to implement such a DRY feature?

Obviously a simple `return Response::error('404')` would not work in the common existence checker method, since it would only return from that method.

It seems that an `Event::fire('404')` is not ideal either since it does not terminate the method it has been triggered in.

Perhaps using an exception would be required here, but I'm unsure about this, or how it should be done in Laravel. Where should I catch a 404 Exception of a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this would be a before filter on your controller.

```
public static $require_user = array(
    'edit_user',
    'show_user',
);

public function before()
{
    $route = Request::route();
    if ( in_array( $route->controller_action, static::$require_user ) )
    {
        $this->user = User::find( $route->parameters[0] );
        if ( is_null($this->user) ) return Response::error('404');
    }
}
```

Before filters get called after your controller is constructed but before the method is called. If a before filter returns anything other than null, the method is not called and thus execution is stopped.

Here we obtain the current route being executed so we can check which method is going to be called against our array $require_user. This lets us use methods that don't require a user id, such as login.

Then we retrieve the user instance, getting the id from what would have been passed to the method. You should probably add more error handling here.

Lastly, we check if the user returned was null, meaning not found. If that is the case we return a 404 response, stopping execution of the method.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, but `return Response::error('404')` doesn't seem to terminate the controller method from being executed. Other than this your solution is fine, and if I change the `return` to `die(Response::error('404'))` it almost does what I want it to do except "dying" also kills Laravel's normal workflow, so for example it doesn't send an actual 404 header just a 200, and who knows what else remains unattended.

Comment: I am sure this method does work because I make extensive use of it. Would you post your controller in full somewhere such as paste.laravel.com

Comment: If I define the "stop_this" filter in my `routes.php` using `Route::filter` and attach it in the controller's constructor with `$this->filter('before', 'stop_this')`, then it indeed stops at `return Response::error('404')` in the filter. However, the `before` controller method seems to be running _after_ the "stop_this" route filter, and it is incapable of stopping the controller at that point. Quite interesting. Are you sure you aren't actually attaching before filters in the controller's constructor?

Comment: Instead of returning the response from the before() method do Response::error('404')->send();

Comment: @ShawnMcCool Nope, calling send() on the Response instead of returning it in the "before" method has not changed that the "before" method does not stop the controlled action method from being run.  I'm using Laravel 3.2.10 by the way.

Comment: After a while I've decided to accept this answer since I think the gist is there: I should be doing this using a before filter, even if I might need to implement it a little differently.

Comment: @Wabbitseason have you find better way to fetch your data once only? I have got the same problem. For most of my controller's methods I need to fetch data from DB and either check if exists or check if a user has permissions to see it. Then I need to use it to generate view etc and I don't want to fetch again or repeat same code for all my methods.

Comment: @demsey: Sadly I haven't find a truly elegant solution yet. Maybe it will come with Laravel 4. For now I'd create a data retriever function that would be called in each method that works with the data, and the retriever would also cache the data so it would be fetched only once.

Comment: @Wabbitseason thanks for the quick respond. I found one solution but it requires core change so it is not the best one. I wanted to discuss that topic here link I also manage to use this solution link but if you want to have access to your controller inside filter you need to use PHP 5.4.4 (my current dev version) It didn't work on 5.3